Name of this projection?
If you project a sphere from its center onto a plane, that's a gnomonic projection. However, if you first apply a three-dimensional Möbius transformation that maps every point on the sphere to another point on the sphere—except for the two "poles" of the sphere, i.e. the two points where the sphere intersects the line that passes through the center of the sphere and is orthogonal to the plane, which are mapped onto themselves—before you perform the gnomonic projection of the sphere onto the plane, is there a name for the projection you end up with? That is, is the combination of the Möbius transformation and the gnomonic projection known by some specific name?
